# Does the User ID returned by https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo changes over time

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, google-oauth

we would like a use the User ID returned by https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo as a unique identifier in an application.

does this User ID change over time ? for e.g. if the email address changes (in Google Apps for business).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user id is a stable identifier. It is not affected by email address changes, that's why it should be used as a key (not the email address).